# Shift planning with Linear Programming

Tags: r, linear-programming, operations-research

The [Modeling and Solving Linear Programming with R](http://www.omniascience.com/scholar/index.php/scholar/article/view/20/15) book has a nice example on planning shifts in Sec 3.7. I am unable to solve it with R. Also, I am not clear with the solution provided in the book.

## Problem

A company has a emergency center which is working 24 hours a day. In
the table below, is detailed the minimal needs of employees for each of the
six shifts of four hours in which the day is divided.

```
     Shift    Employees
00:00 - 04:00    5
04:00 - 08:00    7
08:00 - 12:00   18
12:00 - 16:00   12
16:00 - 20:00   15
20:00 - 00:00   10
```

### R solution

I used the following to solve the above.

```
library(lpSolve)
obj.fun <- c(1,1,1,1,1,1)
constr <- c(1,1,0,0,0,0,
            0,1,1,0,0,0,
            0,0,1,1,0,0,
            0,0,0,1,1,0,
            0,0,0,0,1,1,
            1,0,0,0,0,1)
constr.dir <- rep(">=",6)
constr.val <-c (12,25,30,27,25,15)
day.shift <- lp("min",obj.fun,constr,constr.dir,constr.val,compute.sens = TRUE)
```

And, I get the following result.

```
> day.shift$objval
[1] 1.666667
> day.shift$solution
[1] 0.000000 1.666667 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000
```

This is nowhere close to the numerical solution mentioned in the book.

### Numerical solution

The total number of solutions required as per the numerical solution is `38`. However, since the problem stated that, there is a defined minimum number of employees in every period, how can this solution be valid?

`s1 5
s2 6
s3 12
s4 0
s5 15
s6 0`

Comment: Down-voted! Why?

Comment: Its not clear what the problem is what you want to solve.

Comment: @and That's not true. If you have knowledge in linear programming this question is valid and clear. I also don't get why this is a case for downvoting.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your mistake is at the point where you initialize the variable `constr`, because you don't define it as a matrix. Second fault is your matrix itself. Just look at my example.

I was wondering why you didn't stick to the example in the book because I wanted to check my solution. Mine is based on that.

```
library(lpSolve)
obj.fun <- c(1,1,1,1,1,1)
constr <- matrix(c(1,0,0,0,0,1,
        1,1,0,0,0,0,
        0,1,1,0,0,0,
        0,0,1,1,0,0,
        0,0,0,1,1,0,
        0,0,0,0,1,1), ncol = 6, byrow = TRUE)
constr.dir <- rep(">=",6)
constr.val <-c (5,7,18,12,15,10)
day.shift <- lp("min",obj.fun,constr,constr.dir,constr.val,compute.sens = TRUE)

day.shift$objval
# [1] 38
day.shift$solution
# [1]  5 11  7  5 10  0
```

**EDIT based on your question in the comments:**

This is the distribution of the shifts on the periods:

```
shift | 0-4 | 4-8 | 8-12 | 12-16 | 16-20 | 20-24
---------------------------------------------------
20-4  | 5   | 5   |      |       |       |
0-8   |     | 11  | 11   |       |       |
4-12  |     |     | 7    | 7     |       |
8-16  |     |     |      | 5     | 5     |
12-20 |     |     |      |       | 10    | 10
18-24 |     |     |      |       |       |
----------------------------------------------------
sum   | 5   | 16  | 18   | 12    | 15    | 10
----------------------------------------------------
need  | 5   | 7   | 18   | 12    | 15    | 10
---------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: oh man! What a face-palm moment! I got it working with matrix. Thanks! However, I would still like to know, how is it a valid solution when, every shift has a non-zero minimum requirement.

Comment: The `constr.val` that I used sets constraint to sum of the minima of 8hr shift. For example, first shift minimum is 5 and the second is 7. So, the minimum of both put together is 12. If the constraint was set to 5, then a theoretically, a value of 6 will satisfy the constraint; but, not the limit of individual shifts. This is the second question I have.

Comment: To your second question. Your linear program should solve the question, how many shifts of each type there should be. You can fill the 00:00-04:00 hour shift also with the 20:00-04:00 shift, not just with the 00:00-08:00 hour shift. So fixing your shifts is fixing your decision variables.

Comment: Thanks! The numerical solution in the book is `5,6,12,0,15,0` for si (i=1 to 6).

Comment: I know but I cannot see any fault (the solution is viable as you see in the table) and the objective function has the same value. So there are simply multiple solutions :) Btw I changed my answer a bit, because your matrix was not correct too. I would really appreciat it if you would mark the question as answered :)

Comment: I have marked as answered; would it be possible for you to remove the down-vote to this question, please? Thanks!

Comment: I got you*, enjoyed this. Downloaded the pdf that was linked and am teaching myself this now. Upvoted.

Comment: Can you please elaborate on how exactly you got this "distribution of the shifts" table in R?

Comment: @FelixGrossmann I am working on a similar problem. An additional constraint that I would like to LP is i want to control the number of shifts. Meaning I have provided 6 shift timings but in the output I want only 4 shifts with min of 10 ppl in each shift. Is this doable? can you please help me with the code