# I have a question about optimizing the shifts scheduling (supply) to fulfill the hourly demand as much as possible in R

Tags: r, optimization

I would like to create an automatic shift planning tool through R with optimizing the demand.

Given that I have demand by hourly basis. I need to assign shift based on the demand in order to meet the demand as much as possible. I currently have 6 shifts (will list below).

The objective:

1. to minimize the difference between total supply and total demand
2. to minimize the difference between supply and demand for each hour

Constraint:

1. shift constraint - each hour might have several shifts available to be assigned
2. max capacity - I have the cap of supply. the sum of total shift cant exceed the cap for each hour.

Example:

```
Hourly_Demand <- c(22,19,18,21,22,28,34,39,44,50,49,47,44,43,50,56,56,61,59,59,46,39,34,26) 

Cap <- c(46,46,46,46,46,46,46,46,46,46,46,46,46,46,46,46,46,46,46,46,46,46,46,46,)

Shift_available <-
24Hr shift(A) - c(1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1) 
16Hr shift(B) - c(0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0)
16Hr shift(C) - c(0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0)
16Hr shift(D) - c(0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0)
16Hr shift(E) - c(0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1)
8Hr shift(F)  - c(0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0)
8Hr shift(G)  - c(0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0)
```

The Timeline for Shift_Available is like c(7am , 8am , 9am , 10am , .... , 23pm , 0am , 1am , ... , 5am , 6am) . And '1' means it is available at that specific hour and contribution for 1 supply.

For example, if I assign 1 x shift(A) , 1 x shift(B), then the supply at 7am will be 1 , the supply at 10am will be 2 with the demand is 21 based on the demand vector.

May I have your opinion on how to make this out. Many thanks and apologize if there is anything explained not that clear.

Comment: what is the relationship between shifts and supply? what is the constraint on total shifts per hour?

Comment: You may need to check `lpSolve`. This [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43153099/shift-planning-with-linear-programming) may help you

Comment: Hello Shree, Thanks your quick response.  the relationship between shift and supply is 1 shift = 1 supply (exp: if i assigned 2 x 24-hr shift, then the total supply will be 2 at each hour) and the constraint for total no. of shift is 46 (the sum of each hour cant exceed 46)

Comment: Hi akrun, thanks for your comment. I did check the lpsolve. But I am not able to cater the 2 objectives at the same time through lpsolve. Could you mind to share your code with me ?

Comment: This is a multi-objective problem. There is a large body of literature on this. One popular approach is to "scalarize" the problem by using a weighted sum of the individual objectives.

Comment: @ErwinKalvelagen Thanks for your reply. Can you provide some information/direction to me. I have no idea how to do lol

Comment: See e.g. [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multi-objective_optimization#Scalarizing).